# PhoneGap 3.3.0 - Manually Installing Plugins

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Frustratingly, when I created my PhoneGap 3.3.0 app, it was given the name `HelloWorld` instead of what I wanted: `RealName` - if there's a way to change this without ruining references and stuff in Xcode, let me know! But until I find a way to move away from `HelloWorld`, I need to know what I might be doing wrong when manually installing plugins. What happens now is that the manually included JS files for plugins end up causing JS errors right away: "can't find variable: require" OR "can't find variable: module", depending on what's called first in each included script.

For example, when I run `phonegap plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-vibration.git`, it complains there's no `config.xml` because it's looking for it in a folder called `RealName` but all that's there is `HelloWorld` (along with a bunch of other folders of course). So... I made a `RealName` folder and copied my `config.xml` into it. When I run the `plugin add` command again, it claims to be successful. Then what I do is find what has been added into the copy of `config.xml` and paste it into the real file. Then I go to the Plugins folder (located at the root(?) of PhoneGap itself) which has the downloaded plugin in a folder `org.apache.cordova.vibration` and I move the .h & .m files to where they need to be.

I just don't understand HOW these plugin scripts, which are called after cordova.js (3.3.0 version... also tried the identical phonegap.js file), can complain that a variable is not defined when it's already been defined at the top of `cordova.js`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you are not very far along, I would suggest starting with a new project and make sure to set the app name when creating `cordova create folder_name com.app.name.space AppName`

Comment: Have you tried updating www/config.xml with the name you want and re-run phonegap build ios?

Comment: @QuickFix I did that on your suggestion and it seemed to effectively destroy my project as it failed on some error about semicolons... Trying to power through and start fresh via Dawson Loudon's suggestion. I'm not freaking out.

Comment: I'm sorry if my advice led you to loose your data. Were you changing your code directly in platform/ios? If yes, that's the expected behaviour of build to overwrite the content of platforms with the content of root and as you said you were using `phonegap plugin add` to install plugins and this command having absolutly no effect on the platform/ios folder untill you build, I thought `phonegap build` was already part of your process.

Comment: Doesn't OSX have a time machine that would allow you to get back your project at the same state as before the change?

Comment: Not if you don't use Time Machine... Some part of me thought that Xcode was smart enough to use its snapshot/archive feature to back things up automatically. It's mostly my fault - I was so distraught yesterday that I didn't remember what happened - instead of doing the usual "copy->paste->rename folder" routine when backing up, I just added "_backup" to my app's folder's name. I knew OSX kept track of these changes but I never expected my Terminal to change its current directory to match the new name! But when I ran `phonegap build`, it built over my backup. Balls. But not your fault at all!